# Symfony constraint LessThan Date

Tags: php, symfony, date, symfony-validator

I use Symfony v5.2
I've created this constraint :

```
$constraint = new Assert\Collection([
            'firstname' => [
                new Assert\NotNull(),
                new Assert\NotBlank()
            ],
            'lastname' => [
                new Assert\NotNull(),
                new Assert\NotBlank()
            ],
            'birthdate' => [
                new Assert\NotNull(),
                new Assert\NotBlank(),
                new Assert\Date(),
                new Assert\LessThan('today')
            ]
        ]);
```

Then I send this JSON with postman :

```
{
    "firstname": "john",
    "lastname": "doe",
    "birthdate": "2030-01-01"
}
```

But the assert is not triggered. It seems that the lessThan is only on DateTime, but not sure.

What I've done wrong ? Do i need to make my own check for a Date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, 2 strings are compared by the LessThan validator

You should convert the request value of `birthdate` to an object of `DateTime` before validation.

Comment: Also the  `NotNull` assert is not necessary if there is the `NotBlank` assert

Comment: Sending a `DateTime` object into the assertion should not be necessary, according to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/LessThan.html#comparing-dates). All that needs to be ensured is that `birthdate` is converted to a `DateTime` object before the comparison.

Comment: @El_Vanja yes, you are right, I changed the answer

Comment: Ok thank you for your comments ! I have a new issue : when I try a future birthdate (like 2022-01-01), I have the lessThan assert triggerd (good) BUT I also have the "This value should be of type string" cause of the Assert\DateTime() and I send now a DateTime object.

This is because I send a DateTime object I know. Do you think I can check that the date is good AND the date is lessThan today in a row ?

Comment: Ok, I found my solution. I created a new DateTime object from the "birthday" data : $formData['birthDayDateTime'] = new \DateTime($formData['birthdate']);

THEN I check like this : 
'birthdate' => [
                new Assert\NotBlank(),
                new Assert\Date()
            ],
            'birthDayDateTime' => [
                new Assert\LessThan('today')
            ]

Thank you :)

Comment: Edit : I think this is not a good thing to do.. If you have an idea how to make it well, I'm interested :)

Comment: In my opinion the best solution is using of symfony form https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/without_class.html,  in the form you can add a field with DateTime type and add constraints in the form. So with the form you don't need to convert, because the symfony form will do it automatically